# Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes in flutter run

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When compiling a Flutter project and running `fluterr run` on a mobile amulator and on a connected device both the assembleDebug fails with:

```bash
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dynamic_color:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':dynamic_color:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have downloaded the android sdk correctly with `flutter doctor` recognizing it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The android.jar sdk is not empty and dart sdk is installed aswell.